# PDO driver exception symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

im on ubuntu12.10 using xampp 1.8.1

i was working on a symfony2 project on a windows machine and im currently working on same project from ubuntu machine.

the problem is when i run commands like

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

it gives error

> PDO exception:could not find driver

whereas i checked my phpinfo and pdo_mysql is enabled.also there are many select and insert queries in my project which are working fine.

also when i run  `php -m` it shows only PDO and not pdo_mysql

is something wrong with the enviornment variable or something like that?

Comment: i'm not sure if this is the case on Ubuntu, but is it possible you are using a different ini file for CLI?

Answer (score 4):

Its possible that the `pdo_mysql` extension is not enabled in your php CLI ini file.

Check your ini file for the `pdo_mysql` extension, you can get your ini file location from `php --ini`. On ubuntu it should output a list of all loaded ini files, look for

`/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini`

and

`/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini`

If either of these two ini files are not listed, then you haven't installed that extension. If they are present, then make sure they extension is enabled inside those ini files.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable the extensions *php_pdo_mysql* and *php_pdo* on **php.ini** file that your symfony project is using, check this on *localhost/path_to_your_project/web/config.php*

Tip: check out you **Apache error log**, there could be something wrong with the load of your extensions. This file is located according to your server configuration.